# Identify Panini album 2014 sans-serif font?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

Please some one can help me to identify this font? Is used on panini sticker's

I tried with many differents font identifiers tool.

[image]

Comment: Hi there! We have a collection of font identification resources, and it is a good idea to try that first. Edit your question and let us know what you have tried without luck. Always good to show a little effort, and chances of getting a good answer increases. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info

Answer (score 5):

Hard to tell at that size, but it looks like Gotham to me:

http://www.typography.com/fonts/gotham/overview/

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I work for PANINI in Ecuador, I receive the arts from Italy with their respective link files. The fonts used are Gotham and Pagode.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will like close [result](http://www.myfonts.com/search/brandon/fonts/) (the image is blurred, thus it is difficult to see the details).

[image]

Comment: Is the second, but i can't download free :( Thanks.

Comment: @Jos3k2 http://www.fontspring.com/similar/hvd-fonts/brandon-text